# session keeps randomly giving Undefined array key while key is defiend

Tags: php, web, session

It was running fine on my local host and when i first hosted the site online it was working fine but when i changed the host i keep randomly getting PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "UID"  when the key UID is defined because the pages wont open with out it

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
          
          $sqlrule = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE  userid = ".$_SESSION['UID'];
```

That is how i user it i know i can check if it is set but i wont to know what causes the issue

Comment: Please share more details - maybe that array key is not used? Also, be warned that your SQL query is widely open for SQL injection. Better use prepared statements

Comment: Is the `session_start()` at the very beginning of your `PHP` code, before any other code/echo?

Comment: _"when the key UID is defined"_ It seems fairly obvious that this statement is incorrect. `var_dump($_SESSION)` to make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: I but the session check if before every time i use session the issue is that sometimes it doesn't work giving this error and other time it works fine it sometimes need a refresh

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem